# pagespeed mod errors - Attempt to destroy unknown SHM segment

Tags: apache, mod-pagespeed, apache-modules

I'm struggling with a pagespeed mod error.

I have tried setting ModPagespeed to 'off' and 'unplugged' in the conf. No difference. I tried to disable it and I still get the same errors in the logs ( sudo a2dismod pagespeed ).

My log is below:

```
[Wed Nov 12 15:12:12.879259 2014] [pagespeed:error] [pid 23124] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.2-4321 @23124] Attempt to destroy unknown SHM segment [1]pagespeed_default_shm/metadata_cache.
[Wed Nov 12 15:12:12.879276 2014] [pagespeed:error] [pid 23124] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.2-4321 @23124] Attempt to destroy unknown SHM segment [1]globalstatistics.
[Wed Nov 12 15:24:33.576566 2014] [pagespeed:error] [pid 23434] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.2-4321 @23434] Attempt to destroy unknown SHM segment [1]<unplugged>/named_locks.
[Wed Nov 12 15:24:33.576705 2014] [pagespeed:error] [pid 23434] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.2-4321 @23434] Attempt to destroy unknown SHM segment [1]pagespeed_default_shm/metadata_cache.
[Wed Nov 12 15:35:50.641622 2014] [pagespeed:error] [pid 23536] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.2-4321 @23536] Attempt to destroy unknown SHM segment [1]<unplugged>/named_locks.
[Wed Nov 12 15:35:50.641699 2014] [pagespeed:error] [pid 23536] [mod_pagespeed 1.9.32.2-4321 @23536] Attempt to destroy unknown SHM segment [1]pagespeed_default_shm/metadata_cache.
```

Permissions on the cache folder are writeable - it's been writing files...

I can't for the life of me figure it out. Help would be much appreciated since I'm not the best at servers.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a month old, but I thought I would post some of what I found, as I was experiencing the same problem.  It appears this is benign:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mod-pagespeed-discuss/uWmkKWjvg-s

And it looks like maybe it's a problem with how the modules are loaded/unloaded - not a problem with the actual operation of mod_pagespeed.

https://code.google.com/p/modpagespeed/issues/detail?id=868